# What is &'a in Rust Language

Tags: rust

I read [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html) that

> A shared reference type is written `&type`, or `&'a type` when you need to specify an explicit lifetime.

Understood `&` is for `shared reference` but did not understand what is the difference between `type` and `'a` in Rust language

In [another location](https://rustbyexample.com/hello/print/print_debug.html) I read this code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: u8
}

fn main() {
    let name = "Peter";
    let age = 27;
    let peter = Person { name, age };

    // Pretty print
    println!("{:#?}", peter);
}
```

What does `'a` in the `struct Person<'a> { }` means?
and can I build the same `struct` using `struct Person<'type> { }` or `struct Person<T> { }`?

And what is the meaning of `name: &'a str`?

And how can I re-code it, if want to avoid using the `<'a>`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I found [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotation-syntax) and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html) and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/lifetimes.html) and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/strings.html) that explains my question.

The `'a` reads ‘the lifetime a’. Technically, every reference has some lifetime associated with it, but the compiler lets you elide (i.e. omit, see "[Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision)") them in common cases.

```
fn bar<'a>(...)
```

A function can have ‘generic parameters’ between the `<>`s, of which lifetimes are one kind. The `<>` is used to declare lifetimes. This says that bar has one lifetime, 'a.

Rust has two main types of strings: `&str` and `String`. The `&str` are called `‘string slices’`. A string slice has a fixed size, and cannot be mutated. It is a reference to a sequence of UTF-8 bytes.

```
let greeting = "Hello there."; // greeting: &'static str
```

"Hello there." is a `string literal` and its type is `&'static str`. A string literal is a string slice that is statically allocated, meaning that it’s saved inside our compiled program, and exists for the entire duration it runs. The greeting binding is a reference to this statically allocated string. Any function expecting a string slice will also accept a string literal.

In the above example

```
struct Person<'a> {  }
```

requires to contain `<'a>` as the `name` is defined using:

```
name: &'a str,
```

which is called by:

```
let name = "Peter";
```

If interested to avoid the usage of `'a` then the above code can be re-written as:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {    // instead of: struct Person<'a> {
    name: String,  // instead of: name: &'a str 
    age: u8
}

fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Peter");  // instead of: let name = "Peter"; which is &'static str
    let age = 27;
    let peter = Person { name, age };

    // Pretty print
    println!("{:#?}", peter);
}
```

As mentioned by @DimitrisSfounis in the comments, in short, "Why is 'a there?" ---- Because the struct definition ties it to a referenced object (in this case, every struct Person instance is referencing a &str) you want to specificly declare an arbitary lifetime and tie these two things together: You want a struct Person instance to only live as long as its referenced object (hence Person<'a> and name: &'a str) so dangling references after each other's death is avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed concise explanation.

Comment: Hi, I found your answer not simple enough for Rust newbies like me. After looking around for quite some time, I'd like to offer a simpler explanation to the question: "Why is `'a` there?" ---- Because the struct definition ties it to a referenced object (in this case, every `struct Person` instance is referencing a `&str`) you want to specificly declare an arbitary lifetime and tie these two things together: You want a `struct Person` instance to **only live as long** as its referenced object (hence `Person<'a>` and `name: &'a str`) so dangling references after each other's death is avoided.

Comment: Thanks @DimitrisSfounis I added your statement to the answer, hope it is helping other :)

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis thank you for the newbie lvl answer haha. This newbie certainly appreciates it <3